# Initial Value Problem Trouble

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the initial value problem: $y' = \sin(y - t)$, $y(0)  = 0$.

I'm not even sure what to do with this other than apply the $\sin(a-b)$ identity. After that I get stuck. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use $z=y-t$ to simply solve it
$$\int 1 dt=\int\frac{1}{\sin z-1}dz
\\=\int\frac{1}{\sin z-1}.\frac{\sin z+1}{\sin z+1}dz
\\=\int\frac{\sin z+1}{-\cos^2 z}dz$$

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dt} = \sin(y - t)$, $\frac{dy}{dt} = \sin(z)$ where $z = y- t$. $t = y -z$ and $\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{dy}{dy} + \frac{dz}{dt}$. Eh...i'm not really sure what to do here

Comment: $\frac{dz}{dt}-1 = \sin(z)$ and then separation of z and t

Comment: I really dislike this prime notation. Why are you taking the derivative with respect to $t$ instead of $y$? -- Oh, so you can substitute it into $\frac{dy}{dt}$. Right?

Comment: so, $\int 1 dz = \int (\sin(z) + 1 )dt$ then $z = t(\sin(z) + 1) + C$. So $y-t = t(\sin(y-t) + 1)$ is my implicit solution. I'm not sure if its possible to get an explicit solution

Comment: $\int 1 dt = \int \frac{1}{\sin(z) - 1}dt$

Comment: $\frac{dz}{dt} = \sin(z) - 1$, $dz = dt(\sin(z) + 1)$, $\frac{1}{\sin(z) + 1}dz = dt$, $\int \frac{1}{\sin(z) + 1}dz = \int 1 dt$. Not sure how to solve the latter integral though..

Comment: i edited the solution

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. The only thing is my professor requires an explicit solution. He told us in an email that it was possible..somehow

Answer (score 1):

It's separable, divide everything by $\sin(y-t)$ and use a substitution, then integrate as normal.

Comment: but if we substitute how do we take care of $\frac{dy}{dt}$?

Comment: Integrate both sides by t, you get integral of left with respect to y equals integral of right with respect to t. Sorry about my lack of LATEX skill